# p.update is a function error in my multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have been making a multiplayer html5 game and when i implemented pipe code i am getting error p.update is not a function. below is my code.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
app.set('port', 5000);
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// Routing
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/static/index.html'));
});

// Starts the server
server.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('Starting server on port 5000');
});

// Game vars
var 
width,
height,

frames = 0,
clients = {},
pipes = [];

// Bird class
function Bird() {
    this.x = 64;
    this.y = height/2;
    this.r = 32;
    this.gravity = 0.5;
    this.velocity = 0;
    this.lift = 10;
    this.time = new Date().getTime();

    this.up = function() {
        this.velocity = -this.lift;
        this.velocity = this.velocity * 0.9; 
    }

    this.update = function() {
        this.velocity += this.gravity;
        this.y += this.velocity;
        if (this.y > height) {
            this.y = height;
            this.velocity = -(this.velocity * 0.8);
        }
        if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = 0;
            this.velocity = 0;
        }
    }
}

function Pipe() {
    this.x = width;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 20;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.topPipe = Math.random()*height/2;
    this.bottomPipe = Math.random()*height/2;
    this.highlight = null;

    this.update = function () {
        this.x -= this.speed;
    }
}

// Updating
function update() {
    frames++;

    if(frames % 100 == 0) {
        pipes.push(new Pipe());
    }

    for(var key in clients) {
        var b = clients[key];
        b.update();
    }

    io.sockets.emit('update', {
        birds: clients,
        pipes: pipes
    });
}

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on('new-client', function(data) {
        width = data.width;
        height = data.height;
        clients[socket.id] = new Bird();
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete clients[socket.id];
    });
});

setInterval(update, 1000/60);
```

client.js

```
// Vars
var 

socket = io(),
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
width = canvas.width = innerWidth,
height = canvas.height = innerHeight,
time = new Date().getTime();

var birds = {
    _birds: null,

    update: function(data) {
        this._birds = data;
    },

    draw: function() {
        for(var key in this._birds) {
            var b = this._birds[key];
            var newX = b.x+((b.time-time)*1/(1000/60));

            ctx.fillStyle = socket.id == key ? "#fff" : "#f00";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(newX, b.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
};

var pipes = {
    _pipes: null,

    update: function(data) {
        this._pipes = data;

        for(var key in this._pipes) {
            var p = this._pipes[key];
            p.update();

            if(p.x > -p.width) {
                delete this._pipes[key];
            }
        }
    },

    draw: function() {
        for(var key in this._pipes) {
            var p = this._pipes[key];

            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.topPipe);
            ctx.fillRect(p.x, height-p.bottomPipe, p.width, p.bottomPipe);
        }
    }
}

// New client
socket.emit("new-client", {
    width: width,
    height: height
});

// Draw
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    birds.update(data.birds);
    pipes.update(data.pipes);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#eee";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    birds.draw();
    pipes.draw();
});
```

I am getting error on the client side in the "pipes" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
   socket.on('update', function(data) {
    birds.update(data.birds);
    pipes.update(data.pipes);
```

`data.birds` and `data.pipes` is an **serialised array of JSON object**, it does not retain its function properties (such as `update`) or prototype methods.

I suggest making the Pipe class accessible to both client and server, and turn `update` into a method. Unless you need to re-assign, using functions as object properties is not a good idea (for example, they take more space rather than using prototype methods).

```
Pipe.prototype.update = function () {
    this.x -= this.speed;
}
// To apply the function
for(var key in this._pipes) {
    var p = this._pipes[key];
    Pipe.prototype.update.call(p); // Equivalent to p.update()
    if(p.x > -p.width) {
      delete this._pipes[key];
    }
}
```

Then you can call update even on serialised objects by using apply. Of course, it's better if you have a function that deserialise data from socket.io into `Pipe` instance.

Comment: but the pipe class is on server. how can we set proto on client side

Comment: If you use something like Browserify or Webpack, you can share code between client and server.